# Analog Switch Breakdown voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier, multiplexer, gain

I'm designing a select-able gain circuit using a multiplexer and an inverting amplifier. Here's an example circuit, using a multiplexer.

[image: gain scaling]

I've read that if you provide a voltage larger than the supply voltage it can latch-up and/or damage the circuit due to too high of a voltage.

My question is do these effects occur when the multiplexer is switched to off? For example, if the input voltage has an amplitude of `Va = 40V`, the multiplexer is supplied with a `5V` source, and the third switch (`10k ohm`) is the only activated line? I'm trying to target voltage ranges from `50mV <= Va <= 40V` with gains of `0.02 <= G <= 20` and the output voltage from the op-amp should be ~`1Vpp` or ~`2Vpp` (referenced to the virtual ground). The frequency response should be anywhere from DC to ~20MHz.

If not, is there another way I can achieve this wide gain range (note: the value of `R5` should be small since the circuit has to be able to handle high frequency signals)? I'd prefer to stick with only solid state components if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your circuit doesn't make much sense: for two of the inputs you use an amplifier as attenuator, for a third one a x1 amplifier. Only for the R4 position you use it as a x10 amplifier.
Besides, why did you choose such low resistance values? For the 10 Ω most analog switches will have a significant on-resistance, even if they're as low as 1Ω: that's 10 %. If you scale all resistances up by a factor 100 you'll have the same attenuation/amplification.

Analog switches with low on-resistances exist, but their inputs are limited to the power supply, and then 40 V is an issue.

You say you want solid-state, but a relay may be the better performer, especially a **reed relay**. Low on-resistance of 150 - 200 mΩ, low off-capacitance, in the order of 1 pF, capable of switching high voltages and high frequencies.

Then your configuration. I would replace R2 and R3 by a resistor divider with taps at :10 and :100. Your third relay (for :1) comes at the top of the divider, from where you also go to the x10 amplifier, whose output goes to the last relay. You'll want to protect the input of that amplifier against overvoltage with low-capacitance clamping diodes.

Answer (score 1):

LAtchup SCR effects on CMOS

**Q**  Do these effects occur when the multiplexer is switched to off?

**A**  YES It can happen whenever the chip is powered up.

This design won't work since CMOS switches are not usually this low impedance to work with 10R 100R ladders without error. YOu need to change your Op Amp into a video Amp with higher impedance for feedback

But the preferred solution that has been around for 20 years is called a Digi-Pot and formerly called a Digital Rheostat ™ by MAXIM.

http://www.maxim-ic.com/products/digi_pot/ general catalog.

You have many options;
**Linear , Log taper // Volatile, Non-volatile // Precision, Non-precision // Single, Dual, Three or more.**

Consider a low cost i.c. here
http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/3166

Comment: many digital pots have a limiting voltage rating (including the one you listed). This is significantly below the potential voltage being supplied from the input. Do I have to worry about this, or should I design around allowable pin current?

Comment: This needs to be done around the pre-amp levels not the power amp. Make sure the interface levels are adhered to. These parts are used everywhere now in cars stereos , consumer products.  Pots are much less reliable. Find a way to insert where this is a lower level  and amplify after but they do have 60V devices but not low impedance.

Comment: Hmm, I think you may have misunderstood my application. I'm trying to scale an input voltage signal with an amplitude between [50mV, 40V] to a 1Vpp (or 2Vpp) output signal to an ADC.

Comment: Oh I see this is new info... perhaps a better total solution is avail if you define the overall requirement.  40V pp 80?  12 bit res.. 16 bit? 20? 32?  serial ADC parallel ? Audio or 65MHz or 1 GHz BW? low power or any power, low cost or any? nom temp or wide temp? required resolution.. required worst case accuracy under what conditions??

Comment: 10 bit parallel ADC with 65 MSPS (ADC10065 from National Semi), ~20MHz BW, shooting for USB powered device, most likely near nom. temp. 40V amplitude so ends up being 80Vpp at max.

Comment: do you need 10bit plus 4 decades of coarse gain control? which gives you 7 decades with poor monotonicity

Comment: Maybe? I'm not too familiar with monotonicity.

Comment: say you have 4 decades of control using 0.1% resistors for decade coarse gain control. The error in the upper range represents significantly more error than the LSB of the  10 bit ADC.  The ADC values will not be monotonic as you step thru all ranges as a whole. there will be discontinuities switching ranges. You need it to be part of one ADC package.

Comment: Oh, ok. It's not necessarily a requirement to be monotonic between different course gains as long as it's monotonic within a particular gain setting, i.e. with Gain=2 and ADC reads 1023, a Gain=1 does not necessarily need to read 512 or 511. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes monotonicit of digital decade coontrol ought to be calibrated with each 3 decade 10bit range, but if off by 1% or 0.1% thats up to you. This is significant high V-MHz slew rate so you need video amps or just 30MHz good attenuators.Ought to be in your question.

Comment: 1% would probably be fine.

Comment: About the potmeters. I didn't check all the types listed on the Maxim site, but for instance [this one](http://datasheets.maxim-ic.com/en/ds/MAX5436-MAX5439.pdf) has a bandwidth of only 200 - 400 kHz, and can't handle the 40 V (though that can be fixed).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a programmable gain amplifier (PGA) such as the [PGA202](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pga202.pdf) as this contains the digital switches and resistors required by your application in a single package.  You may need an input stage amplifier with a gain of 0.1 in order to match the circuit above (so gains of 0.1, 1.0, 10 and 100).

This device will not achieve the bandwidth you require but similar devices exist that may better suit the application.

Comment: I don't know of any PGA with a GBW product of 2 GHz. If they exist a link would be nice.